# Porting a Python Shell Program to a Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I have looked at similar questions that may answer my question but I am still very unclear on how to go about the following:

I can create programs to run in the Python Shell in Idle and I can also set up windows with widgets in Tkinter, but whatever I create in Tkinter is pointless because I cannot figure out how to take my Python Shell code and "wrap" it in the Tkinter GUI.

I have assumed that it cannot be done, and that entirely new code must be written to assist the language that is specific to Tkinter. I am very confused on how to create a well-rounded program without being left with just a GUI "skeleton" with random buttons, labels, entries, etc. and a Python program that is very unappealing and can only run in the ugly little Shell.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you have managed to do and what you want to accomplish. Maybe you could provide an example (ideally not all your code but meaningful part) of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't think he's asking for specific help, but rather a big-picture type of question; essentially "What is a GUI for?".

Answer (score 0):

What you create with Tkinter is not pointless. It sounds to me like you're trying to compile a stand-alone program in Python, using the Tkinter library to provide the GUI. Once you have a script working, you can use a program to compile into a standalone program. Look into using `py2app` on a mac, or `py2exe` on Windows. Google them and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave! I will definitely need py2app for later, but is this going to allow me to, for example, run a python program and not have some outputs appear in a tkinter window and others in a python shell? From what I've researched py2app let's me freeze my program or almost compile it, esp for distribution purposes.

Comment: -1 off topic, the poster problem is not packaging/distribution related

Comment: If I understand correctly, your saying that purpose of the GUI is what the style of code depends on.

Comment: I think the question is packaging related. If you compile your program Joseph, a user will run it by double-clicking the icon. When that happens, the Tkinter window you've coded will open, and that's it. There will be no terminal shell, no other windows opened (unless of course you tell the program to). That means things like `print` statements will not be seen by the user (these will go to error loggers, like Console on mac). The user will only see what happens in your Tkinter window. That is the purpose of a GUI, to allow the user to interact with your program graphically.

Comment: If the purpose of a GUI is so that a user doesn't use the command line (the python shell, as you call it). If your program is still a script (so you start it in the command line with `python script.py`), and you have GUI code, then yes both the GUI and the command line will be visible. If you compile your script, then a user doesn't start it from the command line, and only the GUI window is visible. I hope this helps with your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Porting an application from command line to GUI might require some rework (depending on degree of interactivity you want to achieve).

Basically, in a GUI application, you build a few *widgets* (buttons...) at startup, and then perfom all your actions "on reaction" of user input.  You typically do this by *binding*  *callbacks* onto your widgets (button, input field), and then enter a *mainloop* (or *eventloop*).
You might read this [chapter about events and binding](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

If your application is mainly computing oriented, providing a gui with a "launch" button, and an output field is straightforward. If you perform some command line input, you can switch to widget input at low cost. More interactive apps will require to be architectured toward interaction capabilities.